# how to get the mouse position while the left button is down to select and drag text in web

Tags: javascript, jquery

currently ,I want to make the effect: select text , and then drag and drop it into a certain box  in web page by js or jquery, but when I select the text and drag it, the dimension value can't update dynamic, so my question is that: how to get the mouse position dynamically when the left button of mouse is down to select and drag text? thank you!

Comment: the js function ondrag can address this problem.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/SEZzq/1/

http://jsfiddle.net/SEZzq/4/

http://jsfiddle.net/SEZzq/5/

```
$(window).mousedown(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 1) {
        $(window).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
            $('div').text('clientX: ' + e.clientX + ' clientY: ' + e.clientY);
        });
    }
}).mouseup(function(){
    $(window).unbind('mousemove');
});
```

Comment: thanks Xander, but it still can't work after the left button of mouse down to select and drag the text. Anyway, thanks for your reply.

Comment: I want to make the effect: select text and drop it to certain box in web page, your second link http://jsfiddle.net/SEZzq/4/ give some idea , thank you very much!